# VS2008 C# error ".ctor' not supported by language

Tags: c#, c++-cli

C# code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        TFWrapper tf;
        String lexDir = ".......";
        String lic = "........";
        String key = ".........";
        ArrayList cats = new ArrayList();
        Boolean useConj = false;
        String lang = "english";
        String encoding = "auto";
        tf = new TFWrapper(lexDir, lic, key, cats, useConj, lang, encoding);
    }
}
```

Managed C++ method being called:

```
TFWrapper::TFWrapper(String^ mlexDir, String^ mlic, String^ mkey, ArrayList catList, Boolean^ m_useConj, String^ m_lang, String^ m_encoding);
```

Getting '.ctor' is not supported by the language error on the last line of C#

Comment: Do you mind posting the exact Exception Message + Stacktrace?

Comment: It seems to me that C# and C++ methods have different number of arguments

Comment: Yes fat fingered the parameters on C# fixed it. That is the msg and no stack trace. This is a compiler error.

Comment: Try posting the full error message. Saves so much guesswork.

Comment: What is the exact method signature of the constructor? It should at least show up in the class explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a hunch, but I think you need to change

```
ArrayList catList, Boolean^ m_useConj
```

to

```
ArrayList^ catList, Boolean m_useConj
```

Because Boolean is a value type and ArrayList a reference type.

Comment: Tried that and all permutation, no joy

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this in your C#:

```
tf = new TFWrapper(lexDir, lic, key, cats, useConj, lang, encoding);
```

Also, in your C++ declaration, shouldn't `ArrayList catList` be `ArrayList^ catlist`?